# Should putting custom code in functions.php or created the plugins

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

`function custom_post_type(){//example}
function custom_taxonomy(){//example}`

Should add code *filter hook* or *action hook* custom page, *custom post type*, *custom taxonomy*, etc.. in **functions.php** or create plugins.What is the better method?
Is there the way better than this ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods are correct and won't have effect in performance or functionality of the code you put into the the plugin or `functions.php`.

Any theme related code, like **hooks** and **filters** manipulating output of that theme only should be kept in `functions.php` and other important custom code better be in a custom plugin.

Maintaining a **custom plugin** to hold all your**custom code** is rather a better idea than stuffing it into your `functions.php` file. Benefits:

1. If you're using a commercial or any third party theme and it gets updated, your code in `functions.php` will be lost, this is in case you're not using a Child Theme.
2. In case of theme change, you don't need to get into hassle of copy pasting the custom code to your new theme's `functions.php` file.
3. Code will be organised and code maintenance will become easy.
4. Code like registering CPTs and custom taxonomies is intended to stay despite of theme change, so it better be in a plugin so it stays functional even after theme change.

Other than these, every developer has their own reasons for keeping code in `functions.php` or custom plugin.

Comment: Create folder **inc** or **lib**  to put theme related code.Is it good or bad option?

Comment: Yes, it's a good practice to create an `inc` folder in theme directory and include it in `functions.php`

Comment: Welcome. If you find this answer helpful and agree with my explanation, then mark it as the right answer.

Comment: Maintaining a custom plugin to hold all custom code when using a commercial or any third party theme
And created **Child themes** putting theme related code in functions.php and other important custom code better be in a custom plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the situation, I tend to create them in the `functions.php` file if the theme has templates that need the custom post type installed. But if my theme works fine without the custom post type and it's something I may need in the future for other themes I'd just make a plugin for it.